# How to "Print" Every Element in a List while using "A" Print Function?

Tags: python, printing

I have a list named **feed** that is appended by given for loop.

Then after for loop, I'd like to print those element listed in "A" print function as following:

```
feed = []

for i in range(len(reference)):
    if reference[i] not in nodes:
        feed.append(reference[i])



print(reply_noun[0] + "is related to" + for i in range(0, len(feed) feed[i])
```

The last line is just arbitrarily written without considering Python syntax.

Any guidance change it into working one?

Comment: Is there a _reason_ this has to be a one-liner all crammed into a single `print`? You can do it, but that doesn't mean you _should_ do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `join`:

```
print(reply_noun[0] + "is related to " + ' '.join(feed))
```

[EDIT]

If you want it to work for any list (not just list of strings), and even if you don't, this could be an even better alternative:

```
print(reply_noun[0] + "is related to" , *feed)
```

Comment: He doesn't seem to want a space after the `to`, given that he didn't want one before the `is` for some reason…

Comment: Also, why not just `print(reply_noun[0] + "is related to", *feed)`? That way it'll work for any lists, not just lists of strings.

Comment: That sounds like a better answer to me too. Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: I will make that additional edit to my answer if you allow me to.

Comment: @abarnert, and not just lists - any iterable

Comment: @JohnLaRooy Yeah, good point. `join` already works on any iterable of strings, so that's not an extra bonus to switching to a splat, but it is worth pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to add items to list **feed** and then print all the items as an concatenated string:

```
str = ''
feed = [ref for ref in reference if ref not in nodes]

for f in feed:
  str += f

print(A + "sometext" + str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
print(reply_noun[0], feed)
```

since print does take lists as input as well !
Not sure if it is what you want though !